# css input[type=radio] won't work well on IE 11

Tags: css, google-chrome, radio-button, internet-explorer-11

I have a custom-made radio button, green colored.
everything works well both on chrome and IE11, except the color. On chrome, the color is green as planned and on IE11 the color is black.

I attached here the css and HTML.
here is my HTML:

```
                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
                            <span class="formText">Kitzva</span>
                            <input id="radioKitzva" type="radio" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                            <span class="formText">Itra</span>
                            <input id="radioItra" type="radio" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_Itra_Kitzva" runat="server" />

                        </div>
```

css:

```
    /*EDIT RADIO BUTTONS*/

    /* When the radio button is checked, add a green background */
    input[type=radio] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        border: 2px solid #999;
        transition: 0.2s all linear;
        margin-right: 5px;
        position: relative;
        top: 4px;
    }

        input[type=radio]:checked {
            border: 6px solid #008053;
        }

    input[type="radio"]:focus {
        outline: 0px;
    }
```

Print screen attached :
IE11 : [IE11 - checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuPE6.png) , [IE11 - not checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWCKy.png)
Chrome: [Chrome - checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuSQa.png) , [Chrome - not checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FWV9.png)

Thanks alot for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a similar effect to the radio button in the IE 11 browser, I suggest you add the CSS code below in your above-mentioned code.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked::-ms-check 
{
        border: 6px solid #008053;
        color: white;
}
```

Full modified code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>demo</title>
      <style>
         /*EDIT RADIO BUTTONS*/
         /* When the radio button is checked, add a green background */
         input[type=radio] {
         -webkit-appearance: none;
         -moz-appearance: none;
         appearance: none;
         border-radius: 50%;
         width: 16px;
         height: 16px;
         border: 2px solid #999;
         transition: 0.2s all linear;
         margin-right: 5px;
         position: relative;
         top: 4px;
         }
         input[type="radio"]:checked {
         border: 6px solid #008053;
         }
         input[type="radio"]:checked::-ms-check {
         border: 6px solid #008053;
         color: white;
         }
         input[type="radio"]:focus {
         outline: 0px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
         <span class="formText">Kitzva</span>
         <input id="radioKitzva" type="radio" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
         <span class="formText">Itra</span>
         <input id="radioItra" type="radio" />
         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_Itra_Kitzva" runat="server" />
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support appearance, not with nor without prefix. See [here](https://www.caniuse.com/css-appearance).

The attribute selector is supported since IE 7.0. See [here](https://www.caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_attribute).

edit: I do suggest that you change your `[type=radio]` to `[type="radio"]`. Either should be fine, but the latter is more conforming to standards.

Comment: Thamks, so as I understand from your answer there is no way, using the same css (or by editing few rows) to make it work the same both in IE11 and Chrome?

Comment: correct. IE just doesn't have good input styling options. I doubt that's important though, it's fine if the site looks a little ugly on IE since nobody uses it anymore.